# Density of Sobolev Spaces with negative order

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

A book I'm reading references the fact that $H^{-s'}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is dense $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for all $s' < s$. Is there a reference to this fact in any book? I checked Evans' text, but I couldn't find anything (perhaps I didn't look hard enough though).

Comment: I'll have to check, but my guess is that this is in Adams and Fournier, *Sobolev Spaces*.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thank you, I'll check there as well. After searching around the web, I came across that $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $s>0$. Since $s'<s$ implies $H^{-s'} \subset H^{-s}$, does this essentially give us the result?

Comment: @Curious, didn't you mean that $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ for every $s\in \mathbb R$? If so, which I presume from the rest of what you've said, yes, certainly this gives the result of the question.